# Verify my solution - infinite prime number in ultraproduct.

Tags: logic, prime-numbers, first-order-logic, natural-numbers

My aim is to find an infinite prime number in ultraproduct of N**N/U, where U - nonprincipal ultrafilter on natural numbers N (it contains all cofinite sets). We have also multiplication and relation "<" on naturals and therefore inheritated to ultraproduct.

I took a=[2,3,5,7,11,13...].

I have to prove 2 things:
1st is clear - for every natural m, a is greater than embedding of m into that ultraproduct. It is trivial. I did this.
2nd thing - for any b,c in ultraporduct, a=b*c implies b=1 or c=1 in the sense of ultraproduct.
Then for every coordinate i, bi*ci=ith-prime number. Hence one of them is 1 and one of them is ith-prime number.
But why cant we take b=[2,1,5,1,11,1...] and c=[1,3,1,7,1,13....]? Then a=bc.
Is it related to our relation c in ultraproduct but nor a

Comment: One of $b$ and $c$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: Please learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) formatting on this site. Your question is very hard to read in plain text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b = [2,1,5,1,11,1,\dots]$ and $c = [1,3,1,7,1,13\dots]$. Then $\{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid b = 1\} = O$, the set of odd numbers. And $\{n\in \mathbb{N}\mid c = 1\} = E$, the set of even numbers. Since $O$ and $E$ are complements, one of them is in the ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$. If $O\in \mathcal{U}$, then $b = 1$ in the ultraproduct. If $E\in \mathcal{U}$, then $c = 1$ in the ultraproduct.

---

The best way to answer this problem is to use Łoś's theorem. Consider the first-order formula $\varphi(x)$ expressing "$x$ is prime": $$x\neq 1\land \forall y\forall z(yz = x \rightarrow (y = 1\lor z = 1)).$$

Since $\varphi(x)$ is true in $\mathbb{N}$ for each component of $[2,3,5,7,11,13,\dots]$, Łoś's theorem tells us that $\varphi(x)$ is true in the ultraproduct for the equivalence class $[2,3,5,7,11,13,\dots]$.

Comment: I am stupid. I focused that non principal ultrafilter contains all cofinite sets but totally forgot that it must contain or a set or its complement because it is ultrafilter.. Thanks a lot and sorry for such stupid question. Maybe I will delete that.

Comment: Please don't delete - it's not a stupid question, and others with the same question may find it useful in the future.

Comment: @MaciejFicek On the other hand, if you are satisfied with my answer, you can accept it (by clicking the green check mark below the up / down votes). I notice you've asked a lot of questions that don't have accepted answers - accepting an answer is a nice thing to do because it removes the question from the unanswered questions queue.

Comment: @Maciej:  Indeed you identified the easier part of the problem (infinitude), and gave a clear statement of the difficulty. This is the sort of content we hope to collect at Math.SE.